# Как отдавать Last-Modified?

Tags: php

Доброго времени! Друзья, подскажите, как отдавать `Last-Modified`.
`Google` не индексирует! Вот, к примеру, у меня есть добавлялка новостей на сайт

```
<?php
/* Ссылка на файл крннекта с БД */
include('dbcon.inc.php');
/* Функция обработки формы от лишних символов */
    function clearData($data){
        return trim(strip_tags($data));
    }
/* Если существует переменная text в массиве $_POST зачитываем данные в переменные*/
        if(!empty($_POST['text'])){
            $titlenews = clearData($_POST['titlenews']);
            $text = clearData($_POST['text']);
            $date = date("d-m-Y");
/* Если существует переменная newsfoto в массиве $_FILES зачитываем данные в переменные и загружаем фото на сервер*/
            if(isset($_FILES['newsfoto'])){
            $fototn = $_FILES['newsfoto']['tmp_name'];
            $foton = $_FILES['newsfoto']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($fototn,"images/".$foton);
            }
            mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASS) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die (mysql_error());
            $sql = "
                INSERT INTO msgs
                (msg,date,titlenews,fototn,foton)
                VALUES
                ('$text','$date','$titlenews','$fototn','$foton')
            ";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            Header("Location: admin.php");
            }
?>
```

Правильно будет, если я после Хедера буду отдавать его? Гугл сжалится надо мной?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.mysql.php
Это расширение не рекомендуется использовать при написании нового кода. Вместо него используйте mysqli или PDO_MySQL. Ознакомьтесь также с обзором MySQL API для более детальной информации по выбору MySQL API.

Comment: Это конечно спасибо)Но я о другом спрашивал

Comment: а зачем в добавлялке отдавать last-modified для гугла? у вас админка индексируется или что?

Comment: да и потом. хеадер у вас редиректит на другую страницу, толку от отдачи last-modified

Comment: Вот я и прошу подскажите мне куда его вставлять? я просто думал что при добавлении новости он будет отдаваться правильно! а иначе я буду обманывать поисковик!если буду отдавать ему актуальную дату.Или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Новость ведь на главную страницу добавляется!а не в админку!

Comment: ну на каждую новость хотите это отдавать чтоли?

Comment: по коду именно админка ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

Comment: Код я знаю этот)Куда его вставлять и каким путём? не так чтобы он тупо отдавался при каждом обновлении! а к примеру появилась новость на главной странице и её дата ушла в ласт модифайд?

Comment: на главной странице только одна новость будет всегда? :)